# Multiple Subqueries within a Query

Tags: ms-access, subquery

When trying to manipulate and display date from ONE table, I am having difficulty coding it correctly.

I need to, from the same table, find the amount of Services done per day (Which has been done, based on the Count of ServiceId). I then need to find the OverallCharge (done) and find the min, max and avg of these overallCharge (s) per day (BasicCharge + AdditionalPartsCharge + AdditionalLabourCharge)

I need to display these charges per ServiceDate in the table

My draft is the following but is telling me that ServiceId is not part of an aggregate function.

```
SELECT Service.ServiceDate, Service.NumServices , Min(OverallCharge) AS MinOverallCharge, Max(OverallCharge) AS MaxOverallCharge, Avg(OverallCharge) AS AverageOverallCharge
FROM (SELECT Service.ServiceId, Sum([BasicCharges]+[AdditionalLabourCharges]+[AdditionalPartCharges]) AS OverallCharge, Service.ServiceDate, Count (Service.ServiceId) AS NumServices
FROM Service
GROUP BY Service.ServiceDate, NumServices, MinOverallCharge, MaxOverallCharge, AvgerageOverallCharge);
```

Thanks

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: ok so for example, on Jul 3, we had two services done with a min overallcharge of $375.00, maxoverallcharge of $410.00 and the average charge for the day was $392.50

Comment: I refer the OP to the comment I provided some moments ago.

Comment: Your subquery contains aggregate functions but you have not grouped by ServiceId, hence the problem. If you cut and paste the subquery into a new query, you should be easily able to see the problem.

Comment: @Strawberry I do not see why data is necessary in this case when there is a clear error in the subquery.

Comment: @Fionnuala Because sometimes fixing the syntax ain't fixing the problem.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt but I am really not good at it and new to DB, what is my clear error in my subquery @Fionnuala ahaha??

Comment: As I said above, you are missing group by, this was also noted in a previous post.

Comment: Not to mention you can't `GROUP BY` aliases, aggregate or otherwise.